# Shopify Web Checkout Issue

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-mobile-buy-sdk

I am doing [WebCheckout](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android#web-checkout-). After that, I am getting a callback of that Checkout callback.

I have followed the way which has been written [here](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android#polling-for-checkout-completion-).

```
GraphClient client = ...;
ID paymentId = ...;

Storefront.QueryRootQuery query = Storefront.query(rootQuery -> rootQuery
    .node(paymentId, nodeQuery -> nodeQuery
        .onPayment(paymentQuery -> paymentQuery
        .checkout(checkoutQuery -> checkoutQuery
                    .ready()
            .order(orderQuery -> orderQuery
            .processedAt()
            .orderNumber()
            .totalPrice()))
        .errorMessage()
        .ready()
        )
    )
);
```

======================================================================

I am facing the following issues:

#### **1.** `ID paymentId = ...;`

It shouldn't be paymentId, It is checkoutId while will be received in response of [this request](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android#checkout-).

#### **2.** Not getting *null* value in the response of below code:

```
Storefront.QueryRootQuery query = Storefront.query(rootQuery -> rootQuery
    .node(paymentId, nodeQuery -> nodeQuery
        .onPayment(paymentQuery -> paymentQuery
        .checkout(checkoutQuery -> checkoutQuery
            .order(orderQuery -> orderQuery
            .processedAt()
            .orderNumber()
            .totalPrice()))
        .errorMessage()
        .ready()
        )
    )
);
```

#### - 2.1 If I removed the below line than I can able to get some data:

`.onPayment(paymentQuery -> paymentQuery`

So, code will be look like this :

```
.node(paymentId) { nodeQuery: NodeQuery ->
    nodeQuery.onCheckout { checkoutQuery: CheckoutQuery ->
        checkoutQuery
            .createdAt()
            .updatedAt()
            .completedAt()
            .email()
            .ready()
            .order {
                it.orderNumber()
            }
    }
}
```

In above code, I am always getting **ready=true** (Whether I have purchased the product or not). The ready field is using inside the retryHandler function.

```
RetryHandler.exponentialBackoff(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 1.2f)
.whenResponse(
      response -> ((Storefront.Payment) ((GraphResponse<Storefront.QueryRoot>) response).data().getNode()).getReady() == false
    )
    .maxCount(12)
    .build()
```

#### - 2.2, I am getting *order=null*. I need orderNumber to display, so how can I get that?

==================================================================

#### Expected behavior:

- **In Point 1**, It might be some typing mistake, instead of `paymentId`, it must display `checkoutId`. As it is confusing to the developer.
- **In Point 2**, It must return the needed data.
- **In Point 2.1**, The `ready` field must be changed when the order is successfully placed.
- **In Point 2.2**, The `order` field must not be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution,

**Point 1,**

- It is checkoutId not paymentId

**Point 2,**

**NOTE**: Please make a note that, for getting updated result, you have to remove the defaultCachePolicy from the GraphClient object where we are setting up our shop to Shopify.

Now, [while Polling for checkout completion](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android#polling-for-checkout-completion-), pass HTTPCachePolicy as

**HttpCachePolicy.Default.NETWORK_ONLY**

And the query will be as follows,

```
rootQuery.node(paymentId) { nodeQuery: NodeQuery ->
    nodeQuery.onCheckout { checkoutQuery: CheckoutQuery ->
        checkoutQuery
            .createdAt()
            .updatedAt()
            .completedAt()
            .email()
            .ready()
            .order {
                it.orderNumber()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: true, in the iOS GIT document they have mentioned it as checkout_id but in Android GIT document they mentioned  the same as payment_id